# List Comprehension with Regular Expressions in a Text File Python

Tags: python, regex, list-comprehension

I'm doing a Python course and want to find all numbers in a text file with regular expression and sum them up.
Now I want to try to do it with list comprehension.

```
import re
try:
     fh = open(input('Enter a file Name: ')) #input
except:
    print('Enter an existing file name') #eror
    quit()
    
he = list() #store numbers
for lines in fh:
    lines.rstrip()
    stuff = re.findall('[0-9]+', lines)
    if len(stuff) == 0: #skip lines with no number
        continue
    else:
        for i in stuff:
            he.append(int(i)) #add numbers to storage
print(sum(he)) #print sum of stored numbers
```

This is my current code. The instructor said its possible to write the code in 2 lines or so.

```
import re
print( sum( [ ****** *** * in **********('[0-9]+',**************************.read()) ] ) )
```

the "*" should be replaced.

This text should be used to practice:

Why should you learn to write programs? 7746
12 1929 8827
Writing programs (or programming) is a very creative
7 and rewarding activity.  You can write programs for
many reasons, ranging from making your living to solving
8837 a difficult data analysis problem to having fun to helping 128
someone else solve a problem.  This book assumes that
everyone needs to know how to program ...

I know the general concept of list comprehension but I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Do you consider '7746 12 1929 8827' are 4 numbers or only 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your instructor meant something like this:

```
import re
print(sum([int(i) for i in re.findall('[0-9]+', open(input('Enter a file Name: ')).read())]))
```

I spread it out into more lines so we can read it more easily:

```
print(
    sum([
        int(i) for i in re.findall(
            '[0-9]+', open(input('Enter a file Name: ')).read()
        )
    ])
)
```

To explain what is going on here, let's replace the parts of your code step by step.

You can create the `stuff` variable in the same way as your original code in only one line:

```
stuff = re.findall('[0-9]+', open(input('Enter a file Name: ')).read())
```

All I did there was move the file opening, `open(input('Enter a file Name: '))` into the `re.findall()`, and not bother doing `for lines in fh`.

Then, instead of doing a `for` loop, `for i in stuff` and adding `int(i)` into the `he` list one-by-one, we can use our first list comprehension:

```
he = [int(i) for i in stuff]
```

Or, if we replace `stuff` with what we wrote before,

```
he = [int(i) for i in re.findall('[0-9]+', open(input('Enter a file Name: ')).read())]
```

Finally, we put a `sum` around that to get the sum of all items in the list `he` that we have created.

Answer (score 2):

The solution using list comprehension is:

```
import re

with open(input('Enter a file name: '), 'r') as fh:
     print(sum(int(i) for i in re.findall('[0-9]+', fh.read())))
```

Explanation:

•   The `with` statement is used to open the file and automatically close it after the indented block is executed.

•   `re.findall('[0-9]+', fh.read())` returns a list of all the numbers in the file as strings.

•   The list comprehension `int(i) for i in re.findall('[0-9]+', fh.read())` converts each string to an integer.

•   Finally, `sum()` calculates the sum of all the integers in the list.

Answer (score 0):

hope this solution helps you

**File text:**

[image]

```
import re
with open('./sum_numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    # this is the line for sum all numbers in the file
    print(sum([int(no) for no in re.findall('\d+', f.read())])) # 91
```